# Start Movieclip after a certain amount of seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, movieclip

I'm trying to start a movieclip after X amount of seconds, any suggestions? I really appreciate any help I can get. I'm using Actionscript 3.

Answer (score 0):

Add an EnterFrame listener to your MC's parent, count the required amount of seconds, then start the play of your MC and drop the listener. Or, use `flash.utils.setTimeout` function to call a wrapper to `yourMC.play()`.

```
var framesLeft:int=100; // choose
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,countdown); // here we add the listener
function countdown(e:Event):void { // the listener itself
    framesLeft--; // count down from 100
    if (framesLeft<0) { // wow, there was 0
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,countdown); // "drop" listener
        yourMC.play(); // MC's the delayed start
    }
}
```

Comment: "Add an EnterFrame listener to your MC's parent, count the required amount of seconds, then start the play of your MC and drop the listener." Can you give me an example of what you mean and comment in some explanation?

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking this is all by frames? What I'm confused about is i'de like to delay it in seconds. I'm not using the timeline really in the entire movie, its all actionscript.

Comment: While yes, it's in frames, you can align it to seconds by calling `var framesLeft:int=Math.ceil(seconds*stage.frameRate);` Also you can do `flash.utils.setTimeout(seconds*1000, function(){yourMC.play()});` to delay via timer.